# how to make on/off buttons/icons for a chrome extension?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, content-script

I want to let the user decide when they want to run a script, so that when the browser opens, the "off" icon is showing and no script runs; but when the user clicks it, it changes to an "on" icon and executes a userscript, until the user clicks off. I have two png icons which are 32x32 each: `on.png` and `off.png`.

My two questions:

1. How can I set the default icon to my off.png? I tried this in my `manifest.json` but it didn't set the icon, instead showed a puzzle piece (I presume a default):

   ```
   ...
   "browser_action": {
      "default_icon": {
          "32": "off.png"
          },
      "default_title": "icon"
   },
   "icons": {
      "32": "on.png",
      "32": "off.png"
   },
   "background": {
      "scripts": ["background.js"] 
   }, 
   "content_scripts": [{ 
      "js": ["SCRIPT.user.js"]
   ...
   ```
2. Here's my `background.js`, where I've temporarily made a quick function to try and toggle the on/off based on an `onClicked`

   ```
   var status = 0;

   function toggle() {
   if (status == 0){
       chrome.browserAction.setIcon({path: "on.png", tabId:tab.id}); // so it's set for the tab user is in
       chrome.tabs.executeScript(tab.id, file:"SCRIPT.user.js"); //execute for this tab
       status++;
   }
   if (status == 1){
       chrome.browserAction.setIcon({path: "off.png", tabId:tab.id});
       chrome.tabs.executeScript(tab.id, code:"alert()"); // execute nothing when off
       status++;
   }
   if (status > 1)
       status = 0; // toggle
   }

   chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) {
       toggle();
   });
   ```

*(I should mention that when I load the folder housing my scripts, icons and manifest in "load unpacked extension" and then select "inspect views" to check if there's anything immediately wrong, I see `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :` in the background.js, though I don't know what it's referring to)... and it doesn't seem to show my userscript in the scripts folder*

So, any ideas, help?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Alright, so let me make a few changes to your manifest and background pages.

**manifest.json**

```
"browser_action": {
  "default_icon": "off.png",
  "default_title": "icon"
},
```

That will make the default `off.png`. As for the icons section, read the [docs](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/manifest.html#icons) to see what it is used for, but for now just remove it entirely. Also remove what you have in your contentScripts section. If you want to inject it programmatically then there is no need to list it in the manifest.

Next some changes to your background page to make it a bit more clean:

**background.js**

```
var toggle = false;
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) {
  toggle = !toggle;
  if(toggle){
    chrome.browserAction.setIcon({path: "on.png", tabId:tab.id});
    chrome.tabs.executeScript(tab.id, {file:"SCRIPT.user.js"});
  }
  else{
    chrome.browserAction.setIcon({path: "off.png", tabId:tab.id});
    chrome.tabs.executeScript(tab.id, {code:"alert()"});
  }
});
```

Comment: @tempcode I had just copied your code before, but when I look at it again I see that you missed the `{}` surrounding the `code` and `file` parts of `executeScript` try adding those and see if the error is gone.

Comment: Ok that hurdle jumped, we're almost there. That fix allowed me to switch from off to on *(on my first test I encountered `"Extension manifest must request permission to access this host"` - since you suggested removing the `content-scripts` section in `manifest` where I had `matches` and `excludes`, I added a `permissions` to fix that error)*, but there's one final minor issue: once I turn it "on" I can't click to turn it off, it just stays "on" until the page is reloaded (at least we know that unique `tab.id` works). But that aside, the rest seems to be working. Thanks for your help so far!

Comment: @tempcode Alright, so it seems the problem was that `status` is some sort of keyword so `var status = false` didn't assign `false` but rather `"false"` because status was already defined to be a string. Change the variable name to something like `toggle` instead.

Comment: I didn't know status was a keyword either, but that did it! thanks for your help!

Comment: Note that your icon must be sufficiently small (or else setIcon will fail silently): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37599144/chrome-browseraction-seticon-not-doing-anything